# Magento Negative product price

Tags: php, magento

I need to find a way to create Negative product prices in Magento.
We use Magento both as Online shop and POS and in POS we sometimes need
to give a certain discount that simply can't be accomplished with coupons or shopping cart rules.

I did some googling but nothing turned out. Does anybody know how I could create this?

Example:

1 x Apple iPhone 6   -  € 699,99

1 x Discount with subscription from provider X  -  € -100

Total : € 599,99

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried creating order from Magento admin.

Comment: Which version of magento has used?

Comment: @Muk: Yes, but no solution

Comment: @DharmeshGoswami: We use 1.8

Comment: @Nautilus Could you please update your question with a sample product price and sample scenario for better understanding?

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use coupons?

Another possible way to go with is a **configureable product option**. You need to setup this for each product, however. An option can have a negative price, in your case -100€. You can include an description as text on invoices, but it won't show you "599.99-100.00 = 499.99" but just "499.99" as row total price.